# Use Mic Jack as Headphone jack Arch Linux KDE

Tags: arch-linux, audio, jack, microphone

Is there software other than hdajackretask that allows for a mic jack to be used as a headphone jack. I have windows duel booted on the PC I am attempting this on and I am able to do this using the realtek audio console and have been able to do it in the past using hdajackretask on ubuntu but unfortunately it does not seem to work on arch. Previous answers to this just state that you would need a special jack on the hardware level but then don't eleaborate.

Comment: Not going to solve this issue but I want to comment on the fact that the software you are talking about might use a kernel module to do this, because only the kernel has control over the devices. This seems to be some profound hack. It is well known that a speaker can act as a microphone, in the same way, jack-out can be jack-in.

Comment: @Yvain This does not appear to be the case. Pulse Audio was able to play audio through my headphones but the problem is that I can only hear Pulse Audio's test tone when changing audio. KDE does not appear to even detect when applications are playing audio.

Comment: did you try using jackd ? There is a connection panel and you will possibly be able to connect audio output to jack in

Comment: i know of manjaro users that have used hdajackretask to change audio jacks so it should work ok on arch too